# Convert Perl regex to PHP

Tags: php, perl

I have the following Perl code:

```
$url=~s/\W//g;
```

I'd like to translate this to PHP `preg_replace`.

```
preg_replace("/[\W]/", "", $url);
```

I'm not sure this is correct. I don't really know what it does.

It comes from this function, which formats a URL to a canonical format:

```
sub formatcanonical {
    my $url = lc(shift);

    $url =~ s/-/ /g;
    $url =~ s/\s+/_/g;
    $url =~ s/\W//g;

    return $url;
}
```

Comment: If you're not sure, you should just run it. See what happens. It looks correct, though you don't need to use the `[]` because if you only have one thing in a character group you don't need a group.

Comment: Okay so the problem here is that you don't know PHP, and the solution is to learn it. We can't help you there, but I'm sure you can google for tutorials on line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Always try before asking, you could figure this out if you got this far.

Outside of that you don't need the []'s. The regex itself doesn't change when moving to php (or at least for the common things, when it looks like it has too [php has a page](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.differences.php) that lists all differences). However from what I can see it should work correct either way. Character sets are only useful if they have more then one character. In text the regexes do this:

1. Replaces dashes with spaces.
2. Replaces any continues length of spaces with a single underscore.
3. Replaces any non word characters with nothing. These include `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` and some other special/unicode chars like eg `ëè` etc. Capital \W negates where as \w matches word characters.

Secondly don't change the order its very confusing (and if you actually do it in the code it won't come back as expected).

Thirdly PHP allows arrays as arguments for `preg_replace`.

All together one could do something like:

```
$string = 'Hello im a test-able string!';
echo preg_replace(
    [
        '/-/',
        '/\s+/',
        '/\W/',
    ],
    [
        ' ',
        '_',
        '',
    ],
    $string
);
```

Although the readability is still somewhat dubious. And one might just go for the three preg_replace functions instead, especially once they get lengthy.

Finally if you ever need a playground for regex testing give [regex101](https://regex101.com/) a try, its awesome.

---

Also you made 3 edits during me typing this which I'm going to ignore for now.

Comment: What does the W do in this order? I understand changing dashes to spaces, spaces to blanks, and then what does the W do?

Comment: Added the steps and more text.

Answer (score 0):

The Perl code

```
$url=~s/\W//g;
```

replaces all characters in `$url` matching `\W` (non-[word](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Word-characters) character) with emptiness and assigns the result back to `$url` variable.

Equivalent PHP code:

```
$url = preg_replace('/\W/', '', $url);
```

The number of maximum possible replacements can be set via the 4<sup>th</sup> argument (`$limit`). By default, `$limit` is equal to `-1` (no limit). So the replacement is performed globally (the Perl code uses the `g` modifier to achieve that).

Note, the definition of "word" depends on the current locale settings (see [Escape Sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)):

> A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character,
>   that is, any character which can be part of a Perl "word". The
>   definition of letters and digits is controlled by PCRE's character
>   tables, and may vary if locale-specific matching is taking place. For
>   example, in the "fr" (French) locale, some character codes greater
>   than 128 are used for accented letters, and these are matched by \w.